# Can anyone Assist with this code pertaining discord.js that seems not to be working?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

In the Code shown below is for the bot to respond when its mentioned and it seems not to be answering to the mention

```js
let botTagged = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
if (botTagged) {
if (botTagged.id === '783381382407520276') {
      message.channel.send(`My prefix is "${settings.prefix}" || Or use "${settings.prefix}help"`);
       }
    }
}
```

I tried searching for other answers on https://discord.js.org/ and any other sites that involves discord.js coding if that's how to say it. I've tried changing the code up a bit and no results and no errors but however when it put it in a section its give me an error `ReferenceError: message is not defined` but I fixed that error. Any help is appreciated and I will try whatever I get as soon as I receive a response. Thank you

also may I add that I made a new bot without a single line of code and I didn't work in that either.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this question does not provide enough information to answer the question. The code you posted doesn't seem to include all of the relevant code, and has an inaccurate number of curly braces. What errors are you getting, and on which lines of the code? Try debugging your code by checking the values of each of the variables whenever you send a message, such as `message` and `botTagged`.

Comment: @Cannicide that code is implemented inside of my message.js and if you would like for me to send all of the code ill be more than happy for you to help.

Comment: Sure! With all of the code, it should be much easier to find the source of the issue.

Comment: its over 2000 characters

Comment: You can upload it to someplace, such as [Github](https://github.com/) or [Codepen](https://codepen.io/), and then simply post the links they provide you to your question or to these comments.

Comment: here you go and thanks for helping me 
https://github.com/NoMercyAce/Simple-code.git

Comment: Did you set that github repository to a private one? I'm not able to access it, you'll need to set it to a public repository or directly add [me](https://github.com/Cannicide) to the repo.

Comment: sent the invite

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

If your code is intended to respond whenever the bot is mentioned, and not just when the bot is mentioned at the same time as a command is run, then I need to direct your attention to these lines of code:

```
//Trigger Commands
if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return; //<- Notice this
const cmd = client.commands.get(command); //<- and this
if (!cmd) return;

let botTagged = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
if (botTagged) {
    if (botTagged.id == '783381382407520276') {
        message.channel.send(`My prefix is "${settings.prefix}" || Or use "${settings.prefix}help"`);
    }
}
```

Your prefix/command check is placed right above your mention check! That means, if you do a simple mention like `@Bot what is your prefix`, your code will look at the message and say: "This message doesn't have a prefix, and doesn't match any of the commands on the list; therefore, we should not allow the code to go any further." And because of that, the bot with your current code would only respond to your message if it was something more like `/command @Bot`.

**The Solution**

The simple solution to this is to move all of your code for responding to the mention, and move it above your prefix/command checks. Like so:

```
//Mention response    
let botTagged = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
if (botTagged) {
    if (botTagged.id == '783381382407520276') {
        message.channel.send(`My prefix is "${settings.prefix}" || Or use "${settings.prefix}help"`);
    }
}

//Trigger Commands
if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return; //<- Notice this
const cmd = client.commands.get(command); //<- and this
if (!cmd) return;
```

Comment: so if its moved in the solution shown above it should work and now the mention shall work?

Comment: Nvm thx it  worked and i appreciate the help that you gave me 

Comment: Yep, no problem!